# Wait multiple process, print exit code if any process get exit

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process

What I am trying to achieve here is, via script I'm running 3 different custom application in wait simultaneously, if any application get exit, give alert via notify or print exit code.

System in use: Centos 6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about Bash's `wait -n`, but it doesn't let you know which child process exited. How about a simple Perl script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

sub spawn(@) {
    my $pid = fork();
    die "fork: $!" if not defined $pid;
    if ($pid == 0) {
        exec @_ or die "exec: $!";
    }
    return $pid;
}

# Commands to run
my $p1 = spawn '/bin/bash -c "sleep 6; kill $$"';
my $p2 = spawn '/bin/bash -c "sleep 4; exit 4"';

print "spawned PIDs $p1 and $p2\n";

while ((my $child = waitpid(-1, 0)) > 0) {
    my $code = $? >> 8;
    my $status = $? & 0xff;
    printf "child %d finished with exit code %d (status/sig %d)\n", $child, $code, $status;
}
```

Comment: explaination will do help, not much into perl.

Answer (score 5):

The `wait` command in `bash` (4.3 and newer) has a `-n` option:

> If the
> `-n` option is supplied, wait waits for any job to terminate and
> returns its exit status.

This means that you may do

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &

wait -n
printf 'One command exited with exit code %d\n' "$?"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but -n option not working.
 'wait: -n: invalid option' wait: usage: wait [id]

Comment: @Rakesh.N You tagged the question with tho `bash` tag, but it appears as if you're not running `bash` (or you are running an older version of `bash`). Could you please verify that you are in fact using a recent version of `bash`?

Comment: running bash version 4.1.2

Comment: According to [http://centos-packages.com/7/package/bash/](http://centos-packages.com/7/package/bash/), even CentOS/RHEL 7 has only Bash 4.2, and `wait -n` was added in 4.3-alpha ([http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges))

Comment: @ilkkachu ... 3 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `wait -n` to wait for a child to exit, then test each child to if they are still running with `kill -0`, to see which one just exited, like this:

```
for f in 15 10 15; do
    sleep $f &
    PIDS+="$! "
done
wait -n
for f in $PIDS; do
    if ! kill -0 $f 2> /dev/null; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

`wait -n` only returns the exit status of the child, not which `PID` it was.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately even when using `kill -0` after `wait -n` to see which processes are still running, it's impossible to reliably get exit codes.  This is because (a) if you find that 2 or more processes have exited, then which process's exit code was returned by `wait -n`? and (b) there's now no longer any way to get the other process's exit code (because it may have exited between the time when `wait -n` returned, and when you ran `kill -0` to check on it - and you can't `wait` for it anymore because it's already gone).  `kill -0` has the additional problem of pid reuse, ie. after the process endded, some other process might have come along and been assigned the same pid.  This script illustrates the problem:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function workload {
    # Pretend workload that waits a bit and then returns a random result
    sleep 1
    ret=$(( $RANDOM % 200 ))
    echo "$1 process returning $ret"
    return $ret
}

workload First &
pid1=$!
workload Second &
pid2=$!

wait -n
rc=$?

pid1_running=n
if kill -0 $pid1 2>/dev/null; then
    pid1_running=y
fi

pid2_running=n
if kill -0 $pid2 2>/dev/null; then
    pid2_running=y
fi

declare -p pid1_running pid2_running rc
if [ $pid1_running = y -a $pid2_running = y ]; then
    echo "At least one of the processes has ended, returning $rc, but no idea which (pid reuse)"
elif [ $pid1_running = y -a $pid2_running = n ]; then
    echo "First process ended and returned $rc"
elif [ $pid1_running = n -a $pid2_running = y ]; then
    echo "Second process ended and returned $rc"
else
    echo "Both processes have ended, one of which returned $rc, but no idea which"
fi
```

```
$ bash wait-n-problem
First process returning 199
Second process returning 152
declare -- pid1_running="n"
declare -- pid2_running="n"
declare -- rc="199"
Both processes have ended, one of which returned 199, but no idea which
```

The way I worked around this was to use a sub-shell to run the workload, and capture the resulting exit code into a temporary file.  Then, just using `wait -n` to signal that one (or more) of the processes has exited (ie. ignoring the exit code of `wait -n`).  This ends up being more reliable, although a little clunkier.  (It should also be possible to use an fd instead of temp files, and so avoid needing a functional writable filesystem, but this would complicate things a fair bit.)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function workload {
    # Pretend workload that waits a bit and then returns a random result
    sleep 1
    ret=$(( $RANDOM % 200 ))
    echo "$1 process returning $ret"
    return $ret
}

pid1_rcfile="$(mktemp)"
pid2_rcfile="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f "$pid1_rcfile" "$pid2_rcfile"' EXIT

( trap - EXIT; workload First; echo $? > "$pid1_rcfile"; ) &
( trap - EXIT; workload Second; echo $? > "$pid2_rcfile"; ) &

wait -n

pid1_rc="$(<"$pid1_rcfile")"
pid2_rc="$(<"$pid2_rcfile")"

pid1_running=n
if [ "$pid1_rc" = "" ]; then
    pid1_running=y
fi

pid2_running=n
if [ "$pid2_rc" = "" ]; then
    pid2_running=y
fi

declare -p pid1_running pid2_running pid1_rc pid2_rc
if [ $pid1_running = y -a $pid2_running = y ]; then
    echo "This can only happen if one of the sub-shells has been forcibly killed (before it could write to the rcfile)"
elif [ $pid1_running = y -a $pid2_running = n ]; then
    echo "First process ended and returned $pid1_rc"
elif [ $pid1_running = n -a $pid2_running = y ]; then
    echo "Second process ended and returned $pid2_rc"
else
    echo "Both processes have ended, first process returned $pid1_rc, second process returned $pid2_rc"
fi
```

```
$ bash wait-n-workaround
First process returning 183
Second process returning 185
declare -- pid1_running="n"
declare -- pid2_running="n"
declare -- pid1_rc="183"
declare -- pid2_rc="185"
Both processes have ended, first process returned 183, second process returned 185
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash 5.1 or newer, you can do:

```
while
  wait -np id
  status=$?
  [ -n "$id" ]
do
  echo "process of ID $id exited with status $status"
done
```

> ```
> bash-5.2$ help wait
> wait: wait [-fn] [-p var] [id ...]
>     Wait for job completion and return exit status.
>
>     Waits for each process identified by an ID, which may be a process ID or a
>     job specification, and reports its termination status.  If ID is not
>     given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return
>     status is zero.  If ID is a job specification, waits for all processes
>     in that job's pipeline.
>
>     If the -n option is supplied, waits for a single job from the list of IDs,
>     or, if no IDs are supplied, for the next job to complete and returns its
>     exit status.
>
>     If the -p option is supplied, the process or job identifier of the job
>     for which the exit status is returned is assigned to the variable VAR
>     named by the option argument. The variable will be unset initially, before
>     any assignment. This is useful only when the -n option is supplied.
>
>     If the -f option is supplied, and job control is enabled, waits for the
>     specified ID to terminate, instead of waiting for it to change status.
>
>     Exit Status:
>     Returns the status of the last ID; fails if ID is invalid or an invalid
>     option is given, or if -n is supplied and the shell has no unwaited-for
>     children.
> ```